# How to select ordered categorical columns from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I have a pandas data frame with both unordered and ordered categorical columns (as well as columns with other data types). I want to select only the ordered categorical columns.

Here's an example dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy.random as npr

n_obs = 20
eye_colors = ["blue", "brown"]
people = pd.DataFrame({
    "eye_color": npr.choice(eye_colors, size=n_obs),
    "age": npr.randint(20, 60, size=n_obs)
})
people["age_group"] = pd.cut(people["age"], [20, 30, 40, 50, 60], right=False)
people["eye_color"] = pd.Categorical(people["eye_color"], eye_colors)
```

Here, `eye_color` is an unordered categorical column, `age_group` is an ordered categorical column, and `age` is numeric. I want just the `age_group` column.

I can select all categorical columns with `.select_dtypes()`.

```
categories = people.select_dtypes("category")
```

I could use a list comprehension with the `.cat.ordered` property to then limit this to only ordered categories.

```
categories[[col for col in categories.columns if categories[col].cat.ordered]]
```

This is dreadfully complicated code, so it feels like there must be a better way.

What's the idiomatic way of selecting only ordered columns from a dataframe?

Comment: Is this too complex? `df[[c for c in df.select_dtypes('category').columns if df[c].cat.ordered]]`

Comment: Or perhaps `df[[c for c in df if pd.api.types.is_categorical_dtype(df[c]) and df[c].cat.ordered]]`

Comment: Thanks, though I was rather hoping for a way to completely avoid having to do a list comprehension. This seems like such an obvious task that there ought to be something simpler.

Comment: Probably chain a check on ordered categories to select dtypes

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate directly over the dtypes and return a boolean mask to avoid having to unnecessarily copy the underlying data until you are ready to subset:

```py
>>> categorical_ordered = [isinstance(d, pd.CategoricalDtype) and d.ordered for d in people.dtypes]

>>> people.loc[:, categorical_ordered].head()
  age_group
0  [30, 40)
1  [20, 30)
2  [50, 60)
3  [30, 40)
4  [20, 30)
```

You can also use `is_categorical_dtype` as recommended by @richardec in the comments, or simply perform a comparison with the string representation of the dtype.

```py
>>> from pandas.api.types import is_categorical_dtype
>>> [isinstance(d, pd.CategoricalDtype) and d.ordered for d in people.dtypes]
[False, False, True]

>>> [is_categorical_dtype(d) and d.ordered for d in people.dtypes]
[False, False, True]

>>> [d == 'category' and d.ordered for d in people.dtypes]
[False, False, True]
```

You can also abstract away the `for-loop` by using `.apply`

```py
>>> people.dtypes.apply(lambda d: d == 'category' and d.ordered)
eye_color    False
age          False
age_group     True
dtype: bool

>>> people.loc[:, people.dtypes.apply(lambda d: d == 'category' and d.ordered)]
   age_group
0   [20, 30)
1   [40, 50)
2   [20, 30)
3   [40, 50)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is with `getattr`; I'd pick a list comprehension over this though:

```py
people.loc[:, people.apply(getattr, args=('cat',None))
                    .apply(getattr, args=('ordered', False))]

   age_group
0   [40, 50)
1   [50, 60)
2   [30, 40)
3   [40, 50)
4   [30, 40)
5   [40, 50)
6   [40, 50)
7   [20, 30)
8   [20, 30)
9   [20, 30)
10  [40, 50)
11  [20, 30)
12  [50, 60)
13  [40, 50)
14  [40, 50)
15  [20, 30)
16  [50, 60)
17  [30, 40)
18  [50, 60)
19  [40, 50)
```